# Remove eventListener not working on buttons AS3 - Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, addeventlistener, event-listener

I am trying to remove an eventlisnter on a button so when the button is pressed the animation completes before you can press the button again. But based on my code below you can push the button as many times as you like:

```
var LeftButt:MovieClip  = new left_button();
var RightButt:MovieClip  = new right_button();
var topClip:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(topClip);
     LeftButt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(e){moveItems(e, "left");});
     RightButt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(e){moveItems(e, "right");});  


function clothingApp(event:MouseEvent):void{
     topClip.addChild(RightButt);
     topClip.addChild(LeftButt);

}

function moveItems(event:MouseEvent, SlideDirection:String):void{

    LeftButt.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(e){moveItems(e, "left");});
    RightButt.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(e){moveItems(e, "right");});    

    trace(SlideDirection);
}
```

So technically this code should only run once because I never set up the eventListener again. But you can press the buttons as many times as you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove event listeners, you can't add them using anonymous functions.

Create a wrapper function with the same functions as your anonymous function, and you'll be fine.

```
function moveLeft(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    moveItems(event, "left");
}

function moveRight(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    moveItems(event, "right");
}


LeftButt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, moveLeft);
RightButt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, moveRight);   

LeftButt.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, moveLeft);
RightButt.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, moveRight);
```

Comment: So I moved my addeventlistener outside my function and the remove is still inside. I can still press it as many times as I want.

Comment: @Denoteone, you weren't supposed to move addEventLIstener out of the function, you needed to move the function out of the addEventListener.

Comment: AH-HA (light bulb) I see what you are saying now. Will test and confirm it works. thanks +1

Comment: I think I was trying to save time but not having two different move functions but in the end it just cost me 4 hours of head scratching. Thanks again. Checked

Comment: You can actually remove event listeners that refer to anonymous functions, but only within the function itself (using arguments.callee).